# How do I make matplotlib zoom and pan tool work with line markers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, wxpython

I've developed a program that plots input from a spectrometer. The devices I'm attempting to communicate with are rated to send no more than 3 pixels of bad information (this part is unavoidable). What I'm trying to do is enable a picker to pick the 3 possible bad bits of data so I can account for them in the firmware as these three points do not change. So far, my application can activate the picker (via ctrl-shift-f12 hotkey) and I can select and deselect data points as expected. The problem comes when I try to use matplotlibs zoom or pan tools provided in the NabigationToolbar2Wx(). When I try to use either of these, I get: 
`ValueError: 'markevery' is iterable but not a valid form of numpy fancy indexing; markevery=[283, 286, 290, 292]`
I am using python 2.7.9, matplotlib, with a wxPython presentation.

```
def on_pixel_picker(self, event):
    self.CaptureMouse()
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    line = self.axes.get_lines()[0]
    index = list(line.get_xdata()).index(int(mouseevent.xdata))
    if mouseevent.button is not 1:
        try:
            self.markers.remove(index)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        line.set_markevery(self.markers)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.ReleaseMouse()
        return
    if index in self.markers:
        return
    self.markers.append(index)
    self.markers.sort()
    line.set_marker('o')
    line.set_markevery(self.markers)
    self.figure.canvas.draw()
    self.ReleaseMouse()
```

Here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Spectrometer\ApogeeSpectrovision.py", line 28, in <module>
  application.MainLoop()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 8657, in MainLoop
  wx.PyApp.MainLoop(self)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 7952, in MainLoop
  return _core_.PyApp_MainLoop(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 1016, in _onPaint
  self.draw(drawDC=drawDC)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wxagg.py", line 46, in draw
  FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
  self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1085, in draw
  func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2110, in draw
  a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
  draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 737, in draw
  affine, self.axes.transAxes)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 181, in _mark_every_path
  'markevery=%s' % (markevery,))

ValueError: `markevery` is iterable but not a valid form of numpy fancy indexing; markevery=[283, 286, 290, 292]
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it? My data points are fairly close together so this zoom and pan functionality is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for those who are interested or who possible have the same problem. I will explain the problem a little better first. When panning the plot to the left, the markers would stay in the same position on the screen as the graph moved; meaning the marker would trace the graph as you moved it around. If you moved it so far to the left that the point fell of the line, the Exception occurred. If you moved it to the right, the marker would stay in the correct position on the line, but if you moved it off screen the Exception occurred. The zoom tool from the toolbar didn't work at all. It gave me an exception as soon as I clicked it. Deep in matplotib source code in lines.py, line 730 or so, it checks markevery and plots accordingly; however, if markevery is not in the visible indices, the Exception occurrs.

```
    if markevery is not None:
        subsampled = _mark_every_path(new_markevery, tpath,
                                      affine, self.axes.transData)
```

I put in the fix:

```
    if markevery is not None:
        new_markevery = []
        xdata = self.get_xdata()
        ydata = self.get_ydata()
        for mark in markevery:
            point = (xdata[mark], ydata[mark])
            if point in tpath.vertices:
                new_markevery.append(np.where(tpath.vertices==point)[0][0])
        subsampled = _mark_every_path(new_markevery, tpath,
                                      affine, self.axes.transData)
```

to make sure the point is visible, and to get the new index of tpath.vertices, rather than the index for the whole path. That was the key to stopping it from tracing the graph while panning. This fix also solved the zoom tool problem.